# What's wrong with this Magento code? - Simple example

Tags: magento

I am trying to follow this very popular tutorial at this  url: http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_controllers

I tried the very first test - under "Testing It Out" I did not get redirected to my log in screen and then to the control panel with a blank page. Instead I got ...

Response to the url http://mymagentotest.com/index.php/adminhelloworld/ produces the message below. I tried this over and over, I get the exact same results every time - which tells me that I'm learning how to do it WRONG by my making the same mistake over and over again. I need help, or we need help because I'm sure I'm not the only one.

> Whoops, our bad... The page you
>   requested was not found, and we have a
>   fine guess why. If you typed the URL
>   directly, please make sure the
>   spelling is correct. If you clicked on
>   a link to get here, the link is
>   outdated.

I cannot see what is wrong, everything looks fine to the best of my limited knowledge, I had to guess the structure of the config file. I think that's where the issue is. Here is my code ....

The config file in `app/code/local/Alanstormdotcom/Adminhelloworld/etc` ...

```
<config>
<!-- ... -->
<admin>
    <routers>
        <the_name_of_this_element_is_not_important_it_should_be_unique>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Alanstormdotcom_Adminhelloworld</module>
                <frontName>adminhelloworld</frontName>
            </args>
        </the_name_of_this_element_is_not_important_it_should_be_unique>
    </routers>
</admin>
<!-- ... -->        
</config>
```

The index controller in `app/code/local/Alanstormdotcom/Adminhelloworld/controllers`

```
<?php class Alanstormdotcom_Adminhelloworld_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

`Alanstormdotcom_adminHelloworld.xml` in `app/etc/modules` ..

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Alanstormdotcom_Adminhelloworld>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Alanstormdotcom_Adminhelloworld>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Signed: Baffled, and feeling doomed. I have to try to learn this stuff, for my job, which if I fail, I end up living in a nice box in an alley.

Answer (score 2):

Typically the two bits of XML you have should be combined into `app/code/local/Alanstormdotcom/Adminhelloworld/etc/config.xml` and the second file, `app/etc/modules/Alanstormdotcom_adminHelloworld.xml`, would instead look like this:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Alanstormdotcom_Adminhelloworld>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Alanstormdotcom_Adminhelloworld>
    </modules>
</config>
```

While it might seem like a massive uphill struggle to the newcomer you'll either get the hang of it and become much more employable or learn to use automation tools like [ModuleCreator](http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/1108/modulecreator). Whichever happens you'll look back and wonder how you ever struggled.